# Running an executable from PowerShell does not work with spaces in the path

Tags: powershell

From the PowerShell prompt:

```
\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe
```

will run Paint. So will

```
Invoke-Expression -command "\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe"
```

but if there is a space in the path PowerShell spits the dummy e.g.

```
Invoke-Expression -command "\install\sub directory\test.bat"
```

Which complains:

```
The term '\install\sub' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: For more on this topic, see this Powershell "gotcha"... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803521/powershell-pitfalls/7028380#7028380

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**this**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx) article on Technet, enclosing the path in double quotes is not enough.

The path that you are trying to use must have an **&** (ampersand) in front of the directory or it shall not work.

For example:

```
Invoke-Expression -command & "\install\sub directory\test.bat"
```

Comment: Either use `Invoke-Expression` or `&`, not both.

Comment: More specifically to use `&` with `Invoke-Expression` the `&` needs to be part of the command, something like: `Invoke-Expression '& "\install\sub directory\test.bat"'`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use the invoke operator:

```
&'String containing the path'
```

Note, to launch an executable `Invoke-Expression` is really the wrong cmdlet, better to use `Start-Process`.